# How to make circled enlarge of part of a photo (5Head emote effect) in GIMP

Tags: gimp, shapes, images, resize, photo-editing

Is that possible to make 5Head of someone's head in GIMP?
5Head is a picture of a guy's head with circled enlarged forehead.
I've tried to mark the forehead and do anything with basic tools, but I've failed.

[image: 5Head]

Picture for these who don't know what 5Head is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Warp Transform Tool, set set the tool to a size larger than the head, and in the tool options choose the "Grow area" option.

Example

[image]

Comment: At first I didn't find matching tool for what I wanted to do, because i had 2.8 v. of Gimp. After downloading 2.10 version I could find Warp Transform Tool and it worked exactly how I wanted. Thank you very much, that's it!

Comment: @duccce - this functionatilty also existed in GIMP 2.8 where it was called iWarp, but it was a filter rather than a tool. There was a name change of the tool for 2.10, and it became a tool you can use directly on an image.